# What is require('express'), Function reference or Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I think when we use  `var express = require('express');` , `express` get a function reference of `createApplication()` and when we call express(), it will return `app` object.
My doubt is if `var express` is a function reference then how to use `express.Router()` where express act as an object

Comment: In JS, a function is more than a function.  Confusing I know, but you might want to gen up on how JS prototype language works..

Answer (score -1):

You generally do this with express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json("working"));
```

In JavaScript, everything is an object, even functions. You can add properties to function.